# How to lowercase first word of sentence

Tags: sectioning, hyperref

I have a section like this in my document.

```
\section{\textit{Use case} 5: Restore backup}
\label{sec:UC5}
```

I am using the `hyperref` package to make references that includes the content of the section in stead of the section number. This is all fine.

My problem is when I have a section like this: Use case 5: Restore backup, and referring to it it will look like this inside of my text:

> *some text... Use case 5: Restore backup ... some text.*

But I would like it to be like this:

> *some text... use case 5: Restore backup ... some text.*

note the lower case of the first word in the reference. How can I achieve this?

My document:

```
\section{\textit{Use case} 4: Save backup}
\label{sec:UC4}
\subsection*{Normalforløb}
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. \textit{\nameref{sec:UC5}}.

\subsection*{Undtagelser}
TBD

\section{\textit{Use case} 5: Restore backup}
\label{sec:UC5}
\subsection*{Normalforløb}
Den nye opdatering bliver slettet og backuppen geninstalleres. Backuppen skal verificeres efter installering.
```

I am adding the hyperref package like this:

```
\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,pageanchor=true]{hyperref}
```

Here is a working sample: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5409b0ac60203fdd22253e39

Comment: Please provide an MWE which makes it easier for us to help you. Thanks. Maybe the easiest would be to write `\hyperref[sec:UC5]{use case 5: Restore backup}`

Comment: I am not shure what it is you would like me to add or what you are suggesting. I will add a working example i 2 sec.

Comment: hard to say without more context but almost certainly the markup should be `\section{Restore backup}` not `\section{\textit{Use case} 5: Restore backup}` font commands and explicit numbers are normally to be avoided in headings (well everywhere, but especially headings) then you can arrange that the heading and cross reference macros add `use case` or `Use case` as required.

Comment: You are right about the numbering. But this case is a little odd because the numbers has to be static no matter which changes are made later on. I have just added a Little bit of code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I often has such headings, for example if I write a memo commenting on an agreement: 1. *Section 4.2*: Unreasonable restriction (body text) 2. *Subsection 5.1.2*: Not relevant ( more body text). The section etc refer to the sections in the agreement I am commenting.

Comment: @Sveinung yes that's what I meant about context, hard to tell from just an example `5` if you are referring to a static number from elsewhere or if this is the 5th element in an "enumeration by hand" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses the `\firstToLow` command from [this related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199662/lower-case-first-character/199666#199666):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,pageanchor=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\newcommand\firstToLow[1]{%
 {%
   \renewcommand{\mfirstucMakeUppercase}{\MakeLowercase}%
   \makefirstuc{#1}%
 }%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lcnameref}[1]{%
 \begingroup 
   \let\label\@gobble
   \NR@setref{#1}\lc@thirdoffive{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\lc@thirdoffive}[5]{\firstToLow{#3}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{\textit{Use case} 4: Save backup}
\label{sec:UC4}
\subsection*{Normalforløb}
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
Some text. \textit{\lcnameref{sec:UC5}}.

\subsection*{Undtagelser}
TBD

\section{\textit{Use case} 5: Restore backup}
\label{sec:UC5}
\subsection*{Normalforløb}
Den nye opdatering bliver slettet og backuppen geninstalleres.
Backuppen skal verificeres efter installering.

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of result]

Comment: I now realize that it produces some other troubles for me when using the @ sign in commands like \@title or \f@size. Do you know why this is problematic? I can upload the code if you would like it.

Comment: Here is a working sample: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5409b0ac60203fdd22253e39

Comment: @FireFly3000 Internal commands (those containing @ signs in their name) don't work in ordinary use. See the [TeX FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=atsigns) for further details. If the FAQ answer doesn't help, either open a new question as a follow-up (linked back to this one) including a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) or add a MWE to this question.