# Lower case first character

Tags: fonts, macros

How do you make a macro that takes 1 argument and forces the very first character to low?

So you could write the following:

```
\firstToLow{SOME TEXT INPUT OF VARIATING LENGTH}
```

And then get this output:

> sOME TEXT INPUT OF VARIATING LENGTH

It should be supporting hyperref sou I will be able to write this:

```
\firstToLow{\textit{\nameref{label}}}
```

Comment: `\MakeLowercase SOME TEXT INPUT OF VARIATING LENGTH` (without braces) should do the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the reverse of `\makefirstuc` provided by [`mfirstuc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc), which converts the first letter to uppercase. You can adapt it to lowercase by redefining `\mfirstucMakeUppercase`. This behaves similarly to Bernard's comment, but can deal with any text-block font changing command applied to the text, provided the text to be changed is the first argument of the text-block command, as in the example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\renewcommand{\mfirstucMakeUppercase}{\MakeLowercase}

\begin{document}

\makefirstuc{SOME TEXT INPUT OF VARIATING LENGTH}

\makefirstuc{\emph{SOME TEXT INPUT OF VARIATING LENGTH}}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, wrapping it up in a command so that it doesn't interfere with any other use of `\makefirstuc`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}

\newcommand\firstToLow[1]{%
 {%
   \renewcommand{\mfirstucMakeUppercase}{\MakeLowercase}%
   \makefirstuc{#1}%
 }%
}

\begin{document}

\firstToLow{SOME TEXT INPUT OF VARIATING LENGTH}

\firstToLow{\emph{SOME TEXT INPUT OF VARIATING LENGTH}}

\end{document}
```

In both cases the result is:

[image: First letter has been converted to lowercase]

Comment: Almost there. It still interfers a Little bit. When using your example it Works but when I e.g. use this example: \firstToLow{\textit{\nameref{sec:UC4}}} the output becomes: sec:UC4 in stead of the value of the reference. It also gives an error: Argument of \T@nameref has an extra }.

Comment: @FireFly3000 You are making it difficult :)

Comment: @FireFly3000 That's because `\MakeLowercase\nameref{sec:UC4}` doesn't work.

Comment: It does produce some errors when using the @ operator. I have uploaded a working sample here: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5409b0ac60203fdd22253e39

Comment: Using `\emakefirstuc` instead of `\makefirstuc` solved this issue for me, so I could use `\firstToLow{\nameref{label}}`

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\firstToLow#1{\expandafter\firstToLowA#1!!}
\def\firstToLowA#1#2!!{\MakeLowercase{#1}#2}
\begin{document}

\firstToLow{SOME TEXT INPUT OF VARIATING LENGTH}

\firstToLow SOME TEXT INPUT OF VARIATING LENGTH

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is very close. However, it only works when inserting the text directly in the input field but I am doing something like this: \firstToLow{\textit{\nameref{sec:UC4}}}

Comment: Btw. I am using the hyperref package for the references.

Comment: "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content." `^^`

Comment: @T.Verron: Yes, it is extremely short and of an obscure contents!

Comment: What is the function of the exclamation marks in `\def\firstToLowA#1#2!!`?

Comment: They terminate my character expression. Can be of any symbol which will not be part of the argument.